# Inverse Permutation in Sequential Manner Per-XOR (−1)

Tags: encryption, permutation

I'm trying to understand a protocol proposed in a research paper. There is a step that involves computing inverse Per-XOR. The explanation along with solved example is given below:

"Perform inverse permutation in a sequential manner to get the
concealed string ‘’. For inverse permutation, we use one
pointer/indexer () for traversing over the result computed in step-1.
If  = 0 then the pointer  moves to  position and bit stored on
ℎ location on string  will be placed at 1 location;
otherwise, the pointer  moves to  position and bit stored on
ℎ location will be placed 1 location.
This process will continue till the last bit of the string’’().
"
[image]

Now I understand what is happening and I've already manually solved it. I was wondering if there was another way to understand the transform then the one proposed. Thank you.

Link to the paper.
[Paper Link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334610346_Ultralightweight_RFID_Authentication_Protocols_for_Low-Cost_Passive_RFID_Tags)

Comment: can you edit your question clarifying any subscripts and ranges?

Comment: More importantly, where is the hypothetical research paper's link?

Comment: @kelalaka I've added the link to the paper. The protocol I'm trying to understand is EGP (Extremely Good Privacy).

Comment: @kodlu can you plz clarify, It's only been a couple of months since I started crypto.